# Object Mapper Values Returning Null

Tags: java, spring, objectmapper

I'm using an `Ajax` Post request using jQuery to send data to Spring MVC. Two of those values are `String` data types while the other two are `int`. I get the following error: `Can not instantiate variable of type.....From Integral number...`

I'm receiving the data I sent from the client side into my server side Java code, but the values with the object mapper are null (i.e. `personid = om.readValue(id, MyClass.class);`) And those same lines are where the error points to. Changing `Map<String,String>` to be `Map<String, Object>` will not work either.

Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**JSON:**

```
{
  id:"35",
  firstname : "John",
  lastname : "Doe",
  age: "40"

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mywebservice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object getPerson(@RequestBody Map<String, String> mydata){

 MyClass personid = null;
 MyClass fname = null;
 MyClass lname = null;
 MyClass personage = null;

 String id = "";
 String firstname = "";
 String lastname = "";
 String age = "";
 ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

 if(mydata.containsKey("id"){
  id = mydata.get("id");
}
if(mydata.containsKey("firstname"){
  firstname = mydata.get("firstname");
}

if(mydata.containsKey("lastname"){
  lastname = mydata.get("lastname");
}

if(mydata.containsKey("age"){
  age = mydata.get("age");
}

try{
 personid = om.readValue(id, MyClass.class);
 fname = om.readValue(firstname, MyClass.class);
 lname = om.readValue(lastname, MyClass.class);
 personage = om.readValue(age, MyClass.class);
}catch(Exception e){ ...}

  return helperClass(personid, fname, lname, personage);

}
```

**Helper Class:**

```
public Object getFirstName(MyClass personid, MyClass fname, MyClass lname, MyClass personage){

  return addName(personid, fname, lname, personage);

}
```

**Model:**

```
 @JsonProperty("id")
    private int childid;

@JsonProperty("firstname")
private String firstname;

@JsonProperty("lastname")
private String lastname;

@JsonProperty("age")
private int childage;
```

Comment: Specific reason why your not using a Dto in the method signature?

Comment: Your pojo should have childid and childage of string type according to json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the json?

```
{ 
  id:35,
  firstname : "John",
  lastname : "Doe", 
  age: 40

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm accepting this answer since it was part of what helped resolve the issue, the other thing I changed was `@RequestBody Map<String, String> mydata` to `@RequestBody MyClass mydata`.